# Multiple receivers for a sing EMS Q

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, ems

I have deployed a process in tibco admin and one of the queue(Q in the process starter of this process) configured has always 2 receivers.  I am not sure why this is happening. if i stop this process then it goes to 0 receivers.i have also verified the JMS connections of 2 queues and it is one and the same.   Could someone shed some light on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you deployed it in TIBCO Administrator but in LB (Load Balance) mode so in that case, you will have 2 service instances with 2 JMS connections, as well. Try to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the Max Sessions on the JMS Queue Receiver is set to 2. If such is the case, the Receiver Count will appear as 2.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had the same process in the project twice.